# Can I print my boarding pass in Liverpool airport?

Tags: tickets, airports, liverpool

Is there a facility in Liverpool airport to print my boarding pass?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Isn't that what you do when you check in at the airport?

Comment: @Karlson: I think some airlines may charge you extra to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. From [Liverpool Airport's website](http://www.liverpoolairport.com/airport-information/passenger-information-baggage-security/arrive-airport/) (which is [easily Googled](https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=liverpool%20airport%20boarding%20prass%20print)), under the "Checking in online" section:

> Printing facilities are available at the airport and are located by the information desk. There is a cost for this and passengers should, where-ever possible, print their required documents before arriving at the airport.